Existence of finite group admitting equally ordered isomorphic normal subgroups with abelian and nonabelian quotient groups
Suppose $K$ and $H$ are isomorphic normal subgroups with equal order in $G$.
Let $G/H$ be an abelian group and $G/K$ be a non-abelian group.
It's simple to prove that commutator subgroup of $G$ (or $[G,G]$) is a subgroup of $H$ and is not contained in $K$.
We can construct a group $G$ through semi-direct products where $K$ and $H$ are trivially isomorphic to each other, yet they aren't isomorphic as subgroups of $G$.
My question is does there exist some group $G$ where the above conditions hold while $K$ and $H$ are isomorphic as subgroups of $G$ (Automorphism of $G$ from $K$ to $H$ exists)
I'm questioning this, as for the isomorphism, $\phi : H -> K$, what would $\phi([G,G])$ look like? [G,G] is unique to G and contained in $H$, so how could $\phi$ preserve group structure if all elements of [G,G] aren't being mapped to K?

Wherever you wrote $L$, you meant $H$, right? But I don't know what you mean by "isomorphic as subgroups of $G$", as opposed to plain old isomorphic as groups.

Thank you for catching that...corrected now! Apologies if I'm mistaken, but I'm considering K and H isomorphic as subgroups of G if there exists an automorphism of G mapping K to H, as opposed to K and H being isomorphic to each other in the case that they are abelian with the same order. I'm having trouble defining this, so apologies if my language isn't correct. Does this second set of constraints necessarily imply that there must exist an an automorphism of G from K to H?

OK. So now I need to know what you mean by "the above conditions" in sentence four. There are many conditions mentioned in sentences one through three, it's not clear to me which ones you refer to in sentence four.

K and H are normal isomorphic subgroups of G with the same order. The quotient group G/K is abelian while G/H is non-abelian. I'm trying to understand the isomorphism between K and H and what G looks like, specifically with $\phi ([G,G])$

What is your definition of "isomorphic as subgroups of $G$"?

@Derek, I think OP answered that, a few comments up. It means there is an automorphism of $G$ taking $K$ to $H$.

@GerryMyerson  The definition should go in the question, not in a comment. In that case $G/H$ and $G/K$ are isomorphic.

@Derek, perhaps your comment should go into an answer?

@GerryMyerson I will wait until the OP has included the definition of "isomorphic as subgroups of $G$" in the question.

@Derek, I’ve added the definition to my question. I believe an isomorphism from $G/H$ to $G/K$ cannot exist as $G/H$ is Abelian and $G/K$ is not. This is where my question stems from. Does this group $G$ exist only when $K$ and $H$ are abstractly isomorphic to each other, as in there is no automorphism of $G$ from $H$ to $K$? A group $G$ can be constructed through the semi-direct product of $Z_4$ with itself where $H$ and $K$ are cyclic groups of order 2 (isomorphic). Your comment implies that an automorphism of $G$ from $H$ to $K$, can’t possibly exist in this construction, correct?

If $H,K \unlhd G$ and there exists $\phi \in {\rm Aut}(G)$ with $\phi(H)=K$, then it is routine to verify that $\phi$ induces an isomorphism $G/H \to G/K$ with $Hg \mapsto K\phi(g)$, so $G/H \cong G/K$ and the answer to your question is that no such example exists.

Thank you! Makes perfect sense :)
